# php pcntl_alarm - pcntl_signal handler doesn't fire?

Tags: php, timeout, command-line-interface, pcntl

I'm considering using `pcntl_alarm()` for something, so to test it out I ran a variation of the example you find everywhere when you google pcntl_alarm:

```
function signal_handler()
{
    echo "Caught SIGALRM\n";
    exit;
}
pcntl_signal('SIGALRM', 'signal_handler');

pcntl_alarm(3);

for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    echo "$i ";
    sleep(1);
}
echo "Normal exit\n";
```

Expected output:

`1 2 3 Caught SIGALRM`

Actual output:

`1 2 3 Alarm Clock`

I tried not quoting `SIGALRM` in the `pcntl_signal()` call (since it expects an int), but then the alarm doesn't seem to fire:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 Normal exit`

I'm assuming the `Alarm Clock` output is due to a default handler and my `signal_handler()` is not getting called.  Is `SIGALRM` the correct constant? What am I missing? I'm running via CLI under linux (centos), have tried both php 5.5 and 5.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIGALRM is a constant as you can see by doing:

```
echo SIGALRM; //14
```

Also you need to check for pending signals using 
[pcntl_signal_dispatch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal-dispatch.php) inside your loop.

```
function signal_handler()
{
    echo "Caught SIGALRM\n";
    exit;
}
pcntl_signal(SIGALRM, 'signal_handler');

pcntl_alarm(3);

for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    echo "$i ";
    sleep(1);
    pcntl_signal_dispatch();
}
echo "Normal exit\n";
```

Goodluck!

Comment: The call to `pcntl_signal_dispatch()` was what I was missing.